# DOCSIS 2 vs DOCSIS 3

Tags: networking, modem

I'm considering getting a new cable modem.  Doing some research I found myself on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS.  I'm wondering if it's worth the extra $30-40 for my home network to go ahead and get version 3.0 instead of 2.0.

The table on this page refers to `number of channels that hardware must be able to support`.  Is this referring to my router and network card?

Comment: My two cents: Don't get anything but a Surboard 6120, 6121, or 6220. You'll regret being cheap later if you get something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it all depends on what your ISP supports. If your ISP is on DOCSIS 2, you will have no benefit in buying a DOCSIS 3 modem. The most DOCSIS 3 modems however are backwards compatible and will make you future proof.

Most ISPs will give your connection a certain profile (a speed limit if you will). So, that's something else to keep in mind.

So:

- DOCSIS 3: Future proof, might be overkill
- DOCSIS 2: Cheaper, won't last 10 years.

Comment: I've called them and they do support both v2 and v3.

Comment: @Webnet You should certainly go for DOCSIS 3.0 if your ISP supports it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I decided on `Motorola SB6121 SURFboard DOCSIS 3.0`

Comment: @Webnet - You need to ask if the service YOU are getting suports both.  I know in the case of my ISP only the highest teir supports DOCSIS 3.0 so if you were on the budget plan you would gain very little out of a DOCSIS 3.0 modem.